# Android - Sending Sound with Intent?

Tags: android, audio, android-intent

This is a code for firing an SMS intent:

```
String uri= "smsto:";
Intent smsIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.parse(uri));
smsIntent.putExtra("sms_body", msgText);
smsIntent.putExtra("compose_mode", true);
startActivity(smsIntent);
```

How do I send a sound file (.amr file) along with the message?